# Existence of A Linear Right Inverse Between Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-transformations, axiom-of-choice, inverse-function

Suppose $f : V \to W$ is a surjective linear map between finite dimensinal vector spaces $V$ and $W$. Is the axiom of choice required to show that there must exist a linear map $g : W \to V$ such that $f \circ g = Id_W$?

I was inspired to make this post by the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431584/does-proving-that-surjective-linear-transformation-has-a-right-inverse-require-a/2431613#2431613), which argues that the axiom of choice is necessary if $W$ and $V$ are not assumed to be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See daw's comment on the question you linked -- you can choose a finite basis without the Axiom of Choice.

In general "finite choice" is possible without the Axiom of Choice -- see e.g. [Do We Need the Axiom of Choice for Finite Sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132717/do-we-need-the-axiom-of-choice-for-finite-sets)

Comment: That makes sense. Does this also mean that we can extend a set of linearly independent vectors to a basis for a finite dimensional space without the axiom of choice? If so, then I think I see how to construct $g$.

Comment: Nevermind, the proof was simpler than I thought. Unless I'm missing something, it looks like it comes down to the fact that a linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces is specified by a finite number of choices.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins That sounds about right.